# Overloading of constructors

Tags: c++, oop

I'm having the following inheritance:

Size_(base class) ---->Size2_ -------> Size3_

When I'm calling the constructors:

```
Size3_<int> a(2,2,1);
Size3_<int> b(3,3,1);
Size3_<double> c(1,1,0);

Size3_<double> out=(Size3_<double>(b-a))
CPPUNIT_ASSERT(out==c);
```

I'm getting the following compiler issue(g++):

```
SteerableTests.cpp: In member function ‘void SteerableTests::testsize3()’:
SteerableTests.cpp:22:34: error: call of overloaded ‘Size3_(Size3_<int>)’ is ambiguous
SteerableTests.cpp:22:34: note: candidates are:
Size3.h:107:2: note: Size3_<Tp>::Size3_(const cv::Size_<_Tp>&) [with Tp = double]
Size3.h:105:2: note: Size3_<Tp>::Size3_(const Size2_<Tp>&) [with Tp = double]
Size3.h:100:2: note: Size3_<Tp>::Size3_(const Size3_<Tp>&) [with Tp = double, Size3_<Tp> = Size3_<double>]
```

So the inherited object is seen as base object also. How to tell g++ compiler to choose the lowest in inheritance stage? In Visual Studio, it works though.

P/S: here are the list of constructors:

```
Size3_(const Size3_& sz);
Size3_(const Size2_<Tp>& sz2);
Size3_(const Size_<Tp> & cvsz);
```

Comment: `Size3_` has multiple constructors and the compiler doesn't know which one to pick. But if you don't show the definition of your 3 class template `Size3_` (at least) it will be hard to figure out what's wrong exactly

Comment: You're right. I thought that they're constructors from base classes. It turns out to be constructors from Size3_. I've updated the code.

Comment: What should I do then? How to make the compiler to realize the lower inheritance class, i.e., a-b is Size3_, not Size_?

Comment: As I wrote, I need to see the definition of your class templates to be able to say something concrete.

Comment: It's just a tuple of numbers. If Size3 is constructed from Size2, then the third number is 0.

Comment: You're not helping me to help you

Comment: @DzungNguyen: Try reading [this webpage](http://sscce.org)

Comment: The calculation `a-b` is carried out using `Size3_<int>::operator-()` (or a free operator definition `operator-(const Size3_<int>&,const Size3_<int>&)`. I guess that operator is defined to return `Size3_<int>`. So you attempt to call the constructor of `Size3_<double>` using a `Size3_<int>` object as argument. Hence it tries to find a suitable conversion. Do you have a constructor for `Size3_<double>` that takes a `const Size3_<T> &` for any `T` as argument? Apparently not, so it tries to convert it going through some of the base class constructors and finds more than one conversion route.